# Discovering gravimetric station data, including location and measurement?

Tags: data, gps, api

I would like to refine an precision estimate of local gravity based upon current GPS position. Ideally, similar to the National Weather Service API, I would like to interrogate a server with a REST interface, providing location and accepting gravimetric data in return. If no such service is available, I would consider hosting mgal data and referencing its value by location, possibly with interpolation.

Together with other natural measurements, this gravity data would be an input to a developing Android application. (No, I don't deem the device's native sensors sufficiently accurate for this; thus, I am seeking a benchmark reference.)

Comment: NGS's [GRAV-D products](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/GRAV-D/data_products.shtml)? They're not USA-wide yet though.

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, I had found the GRAV-D project manual, but not the data. Thanks for the link. (If you transform your comment into an answer, I will accept vote that up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The United States National Geodetic Survey has been working on collecting widespread gravitmetric measurements, and publishing them for their [GRAV-D](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/GRAV-D/data_products.shtml) campaign. The data in being collected for the next major vertical datum change in 2022.